# EF seed is not applied when run

Tags: c#, entity-framework, seeding

I need to add some dummy data to my database and wanted to use Seed as described [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/entity_framework/entity_framework_seed_database.htm) however I cannot get it to work. When I run Update-database, it says that it is Running Seed method, but when it is done there is still nothing in the db. This is my code (some fields are abbreviated)

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public AppContext (): base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DBContextInitializer()); //Used for seeding. 
    }
    public virtual DbSet<Attendee> Attendees { get; set; }  
}



 public class DBContextInitializer: CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<AppContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(AppContext context)
        {
            var attendee = new Attendee { Id = 0, FirstName = "XXX" };
            context.Attendees.Add(attendee);
            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I think you should save the changes by calling `context.SaveChanges();`

Comment: Ah, I have tried that as well, didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Hmm.. it's an explicit `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`, doesn't it seed if the database is created? (you need to drop it if it already is created)

Comment: And:  Have you set a breakpoint add the `add` position to check if it's being hit?

Comment: Ah, but I have tried dropping it manually and then applying migrations (and seed) and it didn't seem to help :S No, cannot really debug ef commands.

Comment: @Nisse Have you compiled your code after adding seed method code.Also, use DropCreateDatabaseAlways<AppContext> instead of CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<AppContext>?

Comment: @SonalBorkar just tried rebuilding everything and changed to DropCreateDatabaseAlways, didn''t help. Migrations are applied correctly though, its just the seed which is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to pass AppContext DbContext class in the Database.SetInitializer method. Try below, Compile and run update-database

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public AppContext(): base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<AppContext>(new DBContextInitializer<AppContext>()); //Used for seeding. 
    }
    public virtual DbSet<Attendee> Attendees { get; set; }  
}




public class DBContextInitializer<T> : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<AppContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(AppContext context)
        {
            var attendee = new Attendee { Id = 0, FirstName = "XXX" };
            context.Attendees.Add(attendee);
            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tried this, didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there was a Seed method already defined in Migratons/configuration.cs but all its statements were commented! Adding my own seed code here solved the issue.